# JAVA_HOME issue with Grails

Tags: linux, grails, linux-mint, java-home, sdkman

I just installed Grails through sdkman, ie: `sdk install grails`

Evrything seems to have worked fine,

But when I type `grails -version` this error comes out:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-  openjdk-i386

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

I'm on linux mint Raffaela

I know this should be an error of `JAVA_HOME` pointing to the wrong place, but I can't figure out why, this set up works just fine with my `Android Studio` for example...

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens when you run `java -version`?

Comment: Hi, it throws this: java version "1.8.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_71-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.71-b15, mixed mode)

Comment: Weird isn't the same version, as far as  I remember, I've installed that 1.7 openjdk version because of Android Studio, which runs smoothly

Answer (score 1):

Check your path to java:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Looks like there are wrong path in gradle settings